# PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION failed for Docusign.esign.dll

Tags: docusignapi

I am writing code to use docusign demo machine through Docusign.esign.dll . I have tried using Oauth process  for connecting the docusign.

I have used the code similar to the code motioned in here.

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/test/SdkTests/JwtAuthUnitTests.cs

But I have used my demo machine Integetor key and private key. But I am getting the below error. So do I need to change any setup in my demo machine? Or how do I get valid Integotor key.
I hope my PEM key is causing the issue. So let me know how to preparte that pEM KEy.
I just copied by Private key and created the PEM file using notepad application.
Please let me know do I miss any thing?

**Error calling Login: {\r\n  \"errorCode\": \"PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED\",\r\n  \"message\": \"The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified.\"\r\n}"}**

Comment: Can you please share all the steps which you took to create OAUTH token, starting from creating Integrator Key till call DocuSign API, as there can be issues at many places which can give you above error.

Comment: Steps followed for creating Oauth.

Comment: Steps followed for creating Oauth.1) Created demo machine 2) Created IK 3) Created Seret key 4) Created RSA pait key 5) Copy the private key in to notepad and save that file in location. Then when I try to do I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

BY default, the API points to their live/production servers.  After creating an instance of the ApiClient, set it to point at the demo server:

apiClient.RestClient.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");

Edit:  That was for legacy authentication.  For OAuth, please check to make sure you're pointing to account-d.docusign.com  (notice the -d).

Answer (score 0):

I too found this to be the issue, in the response the bearer token is missing

[image: Image of response partner credentials]

```
<br/><br/>string host = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2"; 
// Note with or without v2 their supplied credentials work<br/>
string oauthBasePath = "account-d.docusign.com";<br/>
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(host);<br/>
apiClient.ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlow(integratorKey, userId, oauthBasePath, privateKeyFilename, expiresInHours);
```

When you use the credentials from the JwtAuthUnitTests - TestConfig all works

[image: Image of response docusign provided credentials]

Comment: Did you find solution? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Steps followed should be:

- Created demo machine
- Created IK
- Created Secret key
- Created RSA pair key
- Copy the private key in to notepad and save that file in location

Missing steps are:

- Granting Consent either using User Consent or Admin Consent, check
  [Service Integration](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html) for details.
- Configure Redirect URI in the Integrator Key, only needed for User
  Consent via  [Authorization Code Grant](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html)

You can use Admin Consent only if you can claim email domain in DocuSign else you need to use User Consent. With User Consent, normally using [Authorization Code Grant](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html), you need to get consent with scopes of `Impersonation Signature`. Once you have user's consent, then you can get new AccessToken for that user using JWT.

Also you need to point to correct host for Demo and Prod,

`account-d.docusign.com` is required for `Demo`
`account.docusign.com` is required for `Prod`

Above host is used to get access token from DocuSign Account Server `(/oauth/token)`, and you will use above host also for getting the baseUri from `/oauth/userinfo` endpoint. Other than these two call, I don't think you will use above host.

In response for `/oauth/userinfo` endpoint call, you will get `base_uri` and `account_id` like below

```
"account_id": "fe0b61a3-3b9b-cafe-b7be-4592af32aa9b"
"base_uri": "https://demo.docusign.net"
```

You will use above `base_uri` and `account_id` for any other API calls, like for creating envelope etc

```
<base_uri>/restapi/v2/accounts/<account_Id>/envelopes
```